# VS code randomly decides to scroll down

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started working with VS Code and I'm having trouble with this problem. I'm just writing a code on one line, and the slider decides on its own to go down to the bottom of a cell. It stops doing that when I close VS code and go back in, but after a few minutes it would do the same thing.
**Update 1**.
Looks like "command + a" is scrolling down a cell as well for some reason. I checked the keybindings but it's not there.
Also, it scrolls down a page when I click on a certain line sometimes, but I can't replicate it. It's very random.

**Update 2**.
I disconnected my mouse and I also disabled all the extensions except for Python. The problem continued.
It seems like there are some lines that result in the slider to go up or down (usually down to the bottom of the cell). It's not only for clicking, I tried using the "left"/"right" keys on my laptop on those random lines, and the slider is doing the same thing. Though again, when I close VS code and open it back in, those same lines cause no problem.
**Update 3**.
I uninstalled vs code entirely and reinstalled it. Problem still exist.
**Update 4**.
I'm starting to think that it may be related to empty spaces. There was a line that caused the issue (I clicked on it and it scrolled to the bottom automatically), and when I removed the empty line above it, it stopped. I'll try to replicate it when I'll see it again.

Comment: Does this problem occur in the python file or in the Jupyter file in VS Code? Which VS Code extensions did you use?

Comment: @JillCheng So far I have mostly been using a Jupyter file, so I can't confirm it doesn't happen in a python file. I'm using the "Jupyter", "Python", and "Python extension pack" packs

Comment: Try to disable all extensions or download and make a fresh install of vs code to check if is some extension... and another thing that you can't discard to test: unplug your mouse if you are using it, the mouse wheel can stop on middle of 2 states and randomly scroll down or up

Comment: @Leo please see my update

Comment: @Penguin this can be very difficult to catch, but you can go Help > Toogle Develoepr Tools, inspect the slider element and put a DOM breakpoint if you can simulate in some way, with this you can inspect the stack trace and discover if this is a impl or bug of plugin or even vscode bug

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eE1M.png

Comment: @Penguin which OS are u using? try to backup your .config / delete it then retry, on fail, try VS Codium or OSS Code (with and without your config) keep the backup and reinstall VS Code as last/second option.

Comment: some additional thoughts should be left here: look for https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28795
or post this issue there if it is a different one/situiation, try also a clean reboot and then without opening a browser before your approach to reproduce the issue in code ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderBrockmeier I have MacOS Mojave. What's VS Codium and how do I go about backing up the config file? I really just started using it about 2 weeks ago so I have a lot to learn

Comment: @Penguin like chrome and chromium-based alternatives there are flavors of vs code out there too. They are all based on VS Code and work with the same extensions. Just dont chat so much with Microsoft in the background...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure this is false

```
"python.dataScience.alwaysScrollOnNewCell": false
```

Another possible issue is that sensitivity is too high

```
"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 1
```

Maybe command + a is scrolling because it is selecting all text, or you overrode a setting. Make sure to check vscode keybinds and your mac's.

Also, ake sure that this scrolling isn't because of you accidentally hitting the touch pad is you are on a lap top. This happens frequently for me. Even if I apply too much pressure beside my touch pad it does strange things.

I'm guessing you are editing a local file not accessible to someone else. If they save their file vscode may scroll some while you are typing.

If all else fails, you can try reinstalling to see if that changes anything

Comment: Where do I check these top 2 parts? And yes, local file and I'm only touching the touchpad to click on the line. I think that the settings might be messed up for some reason. I started to notice a few other problems (though I'm not sure that they are related), like VS is not highlighting enclosing brackets as it used to

Comment: They'd be in your default settings or you can override them in your workplace settings. You can also find them in the gui if search for scroll, but I can't say I know the path off the top of my head

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a go and let you know if it works/fails. In regards to reinstalling VS, will my projects be safe? Is there anything I need to do to make sure they will return to their current state/code/etc?

Comment: Save the files. VScode is a text editor only. You won't lose projects unless you were working vscode files themselves. You will lose your settings not defined in a .vscode/settings.json file

Comment: @Penguin : the collegues are right. You just have to open the project agian, after re-install, the .vscode folder is (a hidden -thats what the dot is for) folder in your home folders dirctory. Beside the settings.json there will be some other ".*"files ...the should remain after un'/reinstall, but having a copy of them can be useful. (In the case you r issue is related to these files you even want to remove them. Vscode will create new ones for you. You will have to reconfigure some stuff then, but may be the fix.

Comment: @BrandonKauffman please see my update. I tried everything you said